# controlling for clustering at id level in mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I have one group ($n=40$) of subjects pre- and post-tested (`time`; coded $0$ and $1$) on a continuous variable (`y`). I also have a `gender` variable coded $0$ and $1$.

Using `R`, I was wondering how I could run a mixed effects model using time point and gender as the independent variables, controlling for clustering at id level?

P.S. I'm interested in detecting a meaningful difference among the average scores between the pre- and post-scores as a whole.

Here is my data in `R`:

```
dat <- {
 set.seed(62)
 data.frame(id = rep(1:40, each = 2), y = rnorm(80, 20, 5), gender = rep(rbinom(40, 1, .5), each = 2), 
 time = rep(0:1, 40))

}
```

Comment: One question I'd have before providing any answer is are you more concerned with detecting a meaningful/statistically significant difference among the average scores between the pre- and post-scores as a whole, or are you more interested in identifying subgroups or individuals who displayed the largest difference between pre- and post-scores?

Comment: @StatsStudent, thanks, mainly I'm interested in the former; detecting a difference between the pre- and post-scores mean changes given gender.

Comment: Logically, you would want to treat time as a factor or change the coding from {1, 2} to {0, 1}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty standard specification.

- Assuming that the conditional distribution of `y` (i.e., residuals from the model) are reasonably close to Gaussian, a linear mixed model is appropriate.
- Interacting fixed effects of gender and time and a random intercept varying across `id` should do what you want.

  - It doesn't make sense to test for differences in the effect `gender` by `id` because [unless you're working with people who are gender transitioning, or certain species of sex-transitioning fish] each individual will only have a single `id`.
  - The variation in `time` effect by `id` is subsumed in the residual variation because there are only two `time` observations per person.
- note that the interpretation of the *main effects* of `gender` and `time` will depend on the contrasts used; switch from the default treatment contrasts to sum-to-zero contrasts if you want average effects. (Or use the `emmeans` package to do this *post hoc*.)

### Frequentist

```
## oldest, provides p-values by default
nlme::lme(y~gender*time, random= ~1|id, data=dat)
## faster, more flexible; load the lmerTest package
## instead of lme4 to get p-values
lme4::lmer(y~gender*time+(1|id),data=dat)
## recent, even more flexible
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(y~gender*time+(1|id),data=dat)
```

### Bayesian

Since you used the [hierarchical-bayesian] tag:

```
MCMCglmm::MCMCglmm(y~gender*time, random=~id, data=dat)
brms::brm(y~gender*time+(1|id),data=dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ben has provided a great answer.  Another approach would be to use the `gee` or `geepack` packages for marginal model (using the default gaussian family for your data).  You would have to pick an appropriate covariance structure and specify that in the `corstr` argument.  In your case this would be:

```
geepack::geeglm(y~time*gender, id=id, data=dat, corstr="ar1", waves=time)
```

or

```
gee::gee(formula = y ~ time * gender, id = id, data = dat, corstr = "unstructured")
```

Comment: Thanks, could you possibly briefly provide an interpretation of your approach?